# Ember CSS - Images not loading in production

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-deployment

I'm building an Ember site and I'm having problems with my images not loading in production.

I'm using the latest version.
I've installed the SASS Module and have a very basic stylesheet in 
*app\styles\app.scss*

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
    background-image: url('/assets/images/StockSnap_8SAODL7HZ4.jpg');
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The SASS module is happily converting that into *app.css*

When I do a basic ember serve this works fine.
However doing a *ember deploy production --activate* to AWS S3 things go awry.

All of my assets get fingerprinted as expected, so my image file becomes
**assets/Images/StockSnap_8SAODL7HZ4-4279bf0a502da08d183b81b67d479b40.jpg**

However my app.css doesn't get updated and continues to look for 
**assets/Images/StockSnap_8SAODL7HZ4.jpg**

I guess I'm missing something obvious but not sure what!

Comment: Is your images directory `assets/images` or `assets/Images`? You have it capitalized in your later example (which will cause issues on case-sensitive file systems, like common production linux servers).

Comment: I would suggest testing this locally as well by doing `ember s --prod`. If it's an issue with the [`broccoli-asset-rev`](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev) package, it should be an issue locally as well.

The other possibility is maybe `broccoli-asset-rev` is confused by the `8SAODL7HZ4` in the filename (maybe it thinks it's already hashed and ignores it), try renaming it.

Comment: Thanks I've changed the capitilized I on images.  Testing with ember s --prod produces the same result - the css file is not updated with a fingerprint resource.  I've also tried renaming the file.

Comment: Sorry you were correct.  It was the capital letter.  When I changed it I changed it in the dist folder not the public folder - which of course changed itself back.

Comment: So, is this question answered - or should it just be deleted - or what?

Comment: I think if Michael turns his comment into an answer it has value.
As a sidenote michael I tried leaving the 8SA0DDDL7HZ4 in and it continued to work so I think it's just the capitalisation on the images folder.

Comment: @ChrisNevill I posted my comment as an answer. 

It's good to know that the psuedo-hash doesn't cause an issue with `broccoli-asset-rev`. I figured it was likely a long shot, but it's always good to check. One gotcha that I did run into with `broccoli-asset-rev` (and the reason why I know a bit about this library) is if you attempt to serve something like markdown (or an SVG) with embedded links (anything that can have links but isn't HTML, JS, or CSS). By default, `broccoli-asset-rev` will only replace links it finds in HTML, JS, or CSS, which will cause broken link issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the pasted URL examples, case sensitivity may be causing an issue here.

If a URL is breaking in production, but works fine locally, I first check for a case mismatch between the URL and the actual file path. This can cause an issue because it's typical that production servers have a case **sensitive** filesystem (especially if you have Linux servers), but most dev machines are usually case **insensitive**.

For example, if you have this site structure:

```
test-site
├── imgs
│   └── test-image.png
└── index.html
```

This will work on a case **insensitive** filesystem:

```
<img src="IMGS/test-image.png">
```

However, it will 404 on a case **sensitive** filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Just to note as I didn't mention it above.  I'm on a Windows machine, which of course is case insensitive, and it seemed even then with ember s --prod the result was not updated in the css file - so it would seem it is ember itself that is doing this in the first instance.